# How to authenticate oauth2 for canvas app?

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, canvas-app

I have a node application deployed on heroku that authenticates with salesforce using oauth2 webflow using connected app. I want to create a tab in salesforce that directly lands to the homepage of node app after authenticating with the logged in salesforce user. Initially I created a web tab but due to content security policy I was unable to load the page. Then I tried creating a canvas app but it also causes mixed content problem as we are redirected to http instead of https during oauth2 webflow. 
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the redirect url in connected app ? Do you have http in the connected app url?

Comment: We have https in redirect url.